# Using Fortran DLL in VB

Tags: vb.net, dll, fortran

I am trying to teach myself calling fortran subroutine from VB. And I am trying to work with really simple examples, but somehow it is not working. I am using Visual Studio 2010, with Intel Visual Fortran. Here is the code I am trying:

```
SUBROUTINE ARRAYTEST(arr)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, ALIAS:"ARRAYTEST" :: ARRAYTEST
REAL arr(3, 7)
INTEGER i, j
DO i = 1, 3
    DO j = 1, 7
        arr (i, j) = 11.0 * i + j
    END DO
END DO
END SUBROUTINE
```

And it builds successfully to create a DLL file. And Here is my Visual basic code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Declare Sub ARRAYTEST Lib "FortTest.DLL" Alias "ARRAYTEST" (ByVal x As Single)
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim arr(0 To 2, 0 To 6) As Single
    Call ARRAYTEST(arr(0, 0))
    TextBox1.Text = arr(3, 3)
End Sub

End Class
```

When I put the DLL file into the directory, and run the code, I got the following error:
A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in ForRun.exe

I googled but didn't find a solution to this, I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what am I doing it wrong and how to fix it. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Never used fortran, but apparently the sub expects a pointer to `real`, and you pass an actual `real` which gets interpreted as pointer. Try declaring `x() As Single` and marshalling as [LPArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx): `Private Declare Sub ARRAYTEST Lib "FortTest.DLL" Alias "ARRAYTEST" (<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), [In](), Out()> ByVal x() As Single)`.

Answer (score 1):

You might try the `DllImport` notation, which I've had the most success with in this particular scenario (FORTRAN from VB.NET).

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim arr(0 To 2, 0 To 6) As Single
        ARRAYTEST(arr(0, 0))
        TextBox1.Text = arr(3, 3)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Module FortranInterop
    <DllImport("FortTest.DLL", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint:="ARRAYTEST")> _
    Public Sub ArrayTest(ByRef x as Single)
    End Sub    
End Module
```

1. The first thing I'll mention is that passing variables `ByReference` is necessary when passing arrays. I'm pretty sure we pass ALL of our variables by reference, but I'm not sure it's necessary if the FORTRAN isn't modifying it. This may be the source of your AccessViolation Error.
2. Secondly, I put the StdCall CallingConvention, but I'm not 100% sure what the default calling convention is in IVF. We always explicitly set it to `CDECL` in our attribute header.
3. Lastly, I would be wary passing 2D(+) arrays to FORTRAN. I don't think I've actually tested or seen it, but I  read on the IVF developer forums that FORTRAN transposes arrays passed from .NET (rows become columns). Just another thing to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but there's a simple answer which no one seems to have noticed. You have declared arr(0 To 2, 0 To 6), but you're calling arr(3,3) which is outside the bounds of your declaration (3 is not contained in 0 To 2). System.AccessViolationException is a common error which usually indicates you have referenced outside the bounds of an array, i.e. you are trying to access something in memory which hasn't been reserved for this variable, hence access violation.

If you used TextBox1.Text = arr(2,3), you shouldn't get that error and the whole thing should work fine.

Hope this helps anyone looking at the question now.